# Equivalent of escape(window.location.href) in PHP

Tags: php, url

I have tried so many combination to  get the correct path of my page like the javascript code

```
escape(window.location.href)
```

I have tried this:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]";
```

but it returns something like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/node/4158?asdf=1asdf=1
```

when the actual page is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/node/4158?asdf=1
```

and if I have this URL: `http://www.mydomain.com/node/4158#comments` for example the result is:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/node/4158
```

i.e. without "#comments"

Comment: The `#` part is not going to be transmitted to the server. It's the "hash fragment" that the browser uses to jump to a specific anchor.

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it is broken and deprecated. Use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: even if i use encodeURIComponent i still get #comments as part of the saved url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fragment identifier `#` is handled entirely client side. The browser will not send it to the server so PHP cannot access it.

The only way to find out what it is would be to include JavaScript in the page that makes an HTTP request including the full URI.

Comment: this is a big problem to me now because after i use this code "escape(window.location.href)" it saves the value to the table and I use php to differentiate url on the current page and the save url on the table. if this cannot be done in PHP is there a way to save only the URL using javascript w/o #comments or ?asdf=1?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is a substring of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - you just need the latter. But instead of constructing the URL yourself, simply use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']`.

Also, since your application is server-side and the fragment identifier (everything from `#`) does not get included in HTTP requests, there is not way to access it in php code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$location = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $location .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
    $location .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
echo $location;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: That's not going to give the `#` fragment either

Comment: as i have explained in my question it does not include ?asdf=1 or #comments

Answer (score 0):

Lot of people saying that the fragment is client side here, but according to the docs [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will return the fragment if present (see the first example in the link).

Comment: Just doing a search for help on this, and noticing that this does not help, because `parse_url` must first have a string to grab the url.  So, where would that string come from?  Not from `parse_url`!  So, sure it works when you have a string with the `#` in it.  But you need to get the string first and AFAIK, you can't get the entire URL with a # in it as a string in PHP, would be nice though!